# How do I have focus effect on normal elements?

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS grid to display some tabular data as shown in example

https://codepen.io/shyamforflex/pen/qBrLQeq

On row selection , the selected row should have a background color.

In current example the background red color is disappearing on mouse click release

```
&-row:active {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: the `:active` Pseudo Class styles the selected element *while* it's active! which means, **after** the mouse click release, it **won't** be active. What you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: This is not doable with CSS alone.

Comment: @JonP it is possible with css

Comment: This question is not related with grid at all. Your problem would be the same for any HTML layout

Answer (score 2):

You could use a radio button hack. Add a hidden radio button to each row. Change your "cells" to `label` associated with the radio button then use `type=[radio]:checked ~ label` to apply the styling. While the HTML is perfectly valid, the use of `input` here is semantically questionable at best.

From your pen you would want something like

PUG

```
 each episode in episodes
    .grid-table-row
      input(type="radio" name="tbl" id=episode.series +"|"+episode.no)
      label.grid-table-cell(data-title="Title" for=episode.series +"|"+episode.no)= episode.title
      label.grid-table-cell(data-title="Number" for=episode.series +"|"+episode.no)= episode.no
      label.grid-table-cell(data-title="Series" for=episode.series +"|"+episode.no)=episode.series
      label.grid-table-cell(data-title="Air Date" for=episode.series +"|"+episode.no)= episode.airdate
```

SCSS

```
.grid-table {
  display: grid;

  /*Additional code removed for brevity*/

  input[type=radio] {display:none}
 
  input:checked ~ label {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Compiled Demo:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.grid-table {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-table-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr) repeat(2, 1fr);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.grid-table-row:first-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-table-row:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-table input:checked~label {
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-table-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e4e2;
}

.grid-table-cell {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid-table-cell:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<h1>Random Dr Who Tabular Data With CSS Grid</h1>
<div class="grid-table">
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <div class="grid-table-cell">Title</div>
    <div class="grid-table-cell">Episode Number</div>
    <div class="grid-table-cell">Series</div>
    <div class="grid-table-cell">Air Date</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <input type="radio" name="tbl" id="7|239" />
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Title" for="7|239">The Name of the Doctor</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Number" for="7|239">239</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Series" for="7|239">7</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Air Date" for="7|239">05/18/2013</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <input type="radio" name="tbl" id="Special|1" />
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Title" for="Special|1">The Day of the Doctor</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Number" for="Special|1">1</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Series" for="Special|1">Special</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Air Date" for="Special|1">11/23/2013</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <input type="radio" name="tbl" id="Special|2" />
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Title" for="Special|2">The Time of the Doctor</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Number" for="Special|2">2</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Series" for="Special|2">Special</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Air Date" for="Special|2">11/25/2013</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-table-row">
    <input type="radio" name="tbl" id="Special|3" />
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Title" for="Special|3">The Salary of the Doctor</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Number" for="Special|3">3</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Series" for="Special|3">Special</label>
    <label class="grid-table-cell" data-title="Air Date" for="Special|3">6/25/2015</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the table is not meant to be submitted; therefore, it's not semantically correct to use input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: @KoutaNakano, you may be correct, hence the use of the word "hack". There is a lot to cover in that link, can you provide a quote from there to support your claim. I believe it is valid HTML, just not necessarily semantically correct, and also may not be great from an accessibility front.

Comment: The very first sentence, sir. "The <input> HTML element is used to create interactive controls for web-based forms in order to accept data from the user"

Comment: For elements to be simply interactive, not the data to be submitted, using tabindex is the correct way to apply focus on elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Keyboard

Comment: @KoutaNakano, just like me to miss the first sentence! Though I was looking for something more explicit, that is a little more implicit. But thanks. Editied my answer to highlight the concern.

Answer (score 1):

:focus can work for what you want to achieve only if the element is an focusable element such as anchor link or inputs. Please refer to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Keyboard) for more information.

**Solution**
There is a way to add focusability to normal elements. Set [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Keyboard) to each row so that the elements become focusable.

**Set tabindex to .grid-table-row**

```
  each episode in episodes
    .grid-table-row(tabindex="0")
```

**Replace &-row:active with below**

```
&-row:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

However, this method should only be used for web accessbility, which means only the interactive elements should be focusable.

Comment: Is there a reason for setting `tab-index` to the index of episode, when according to the MDN article you linked to you should "Avoid using tabindex attribute greater than zero"?

Comment: oh you are right. Let me edit my answer, thanks!